# My UI get frozen while I add each line of a text file in a List

Tags: c#, user-interface, freeze

My UI get frozen while I add each line of a text file in a List.

This is my current code :

```
private void LoadProxies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    dialog.Title = "Select your Proxies file";
    dialog.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";

    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        int list = proxiesList.Count;

        Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(file), line =>
        {
            if (line != null && line.Contains(":"))
            {
                proxiesList.Add(line);

                list++;

                InvokeUI(() => { Proxies.Text = list.ToString(); });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the InvokeUI method :

```
private void InvokeUI(Action a)
{
    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(a));
}
```

I tried using `Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(file), line => ...` and `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...` but it's not fixing my problem.

How can I solve this ? Thanks.

Comment: How big is the file in question?

Comment: It's most probably not a good idea to use Parallel.ForEach here at all. Have you measured (profiled) its impact? IMHO there's not enough work for the parallel loop. Apart from that sharing list and incrementing it (list++) is not a good idea. I hope are you using a thread safe collection like ConcurrentBag<T> and not List<T> for proxiesList.

Comment: Side note: please even if you create [MCVE] post code that looks correct. It was very questionable idea to remove locking from your actual code when creating sample. You got lucky to get answer this time, but in most cases discussion will be completely derailed into talking about proper multithreaded code (same applies to SQL injections samples in posted code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My UI get frozen while I add each line of a text file in a List

The problem with your code is that it is a rather tight loop and if the file is large the following line will be called a great deal of times per second:

```
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(a));
```

This would result in the Windows Message Pump being flooded with update UI requests.

A better action is to either:

1. Since all you are doing is trying to display the numeric value of `list` on screen, consider updating say once a second by way of a Windows Forms timer rather than calling `BeginInvoke`
2. If you must update from a worker thread, don't `BeginInvoke` for each item, consider updating in batches.  In this case perhaps update every `100`

Alternatively you may want to consider TPL DataFlow